# I want to join 3 tables and aggregate records of two columns from 2 of those tables while avoiding record duplication

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have 3 tables

A:

```
---------------
  id  |  name 
---------------
   1  |   A
---------------
   2  |   B
---------------
```

B:

```
-----------------------
  id  |  val   | A_id
-----------------------
   1  |  10    |  1
-----------------------
   2  |  20    |  2
-----------------------
   3  |  30    |  2
-----------------------
```

C:

```
-----------------------
  id  |  val   | B_id
-----------------------
   1  |  40    |  2
-----------------------
   2  |  50    |  2
-----------------------
   3  |  60    |  2
-----------------------
```

How do I get this result:

```
----------------------------
  A_name  | B_val  | C_val
----------------------------
     A    |  10    |   0
----------------------------
     B    |  50    |  150
----------------------------
```

I've tried to do this:

```
SELECT A.name, SUM(COALESCE(B.val,0)), SUM(COALESCE(C.val,0)) 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.A_id
LEFT JOIN C ON B.id = C.B_id
GROUP BY A
```

But it returned this instead :

```
----------------------------
  A_name  | B_val  | C_val
----------------------------
     A    |  10    |   0
----------------------------
     B    |  90    |  150
----------------------------
```

I suppose it's because C has 3 records that are related to B, so the second record of B is multiplied by three. What's the best way to get the result that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the calculations into subselects:

```
select tablea.id, tablea.name, B.B_val, C.C_val FROM tablea
LEFT JOIN
(select tablea.id AS id, SUM(COALESCE(tableb.val,0)) as B_val
from tablea left join tableb on tablea.id = tableb.A_id
group by tablea.id) AS B ON tablea.id = B.id
LEFT JOIN
(select tablea.id AS id, SUM(COALESCE(tablec.valc,0)) as C_val
from tablea left join tableb on tablea.id = tableb.A_id
left join tablec on tablec.B_id = tableb.id
group by tablea.id) AS C on tablea.id = C.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c268/14

EDIT, I had SQL Fiddle set for MySQL. Nothing changes in the code, but here's postgres
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4c268/1

Answer (score 0):

Split the query in two and then use those subqueries as data source for a third one:

```
-- The first query (it returns the sum of b.val)
select a.id, a.name, sum(b.val) as sum_b_val
from a left join b on a.id = b.a_id
group by a.id;

-- The second query (it returns the sum of c.val)
select b.a_id, sum(c.val) as sum_c_val
from b left join c on b.id = c.b_id
group by b.a_id;

-- Put it all together
select
  q1.name, 
  coalesce(q1.sum_b_val, 0) as sum_b_val, 
  coalesce(q2.sum_c_val, 0) as sum_c_val
from
  (
    select a.id, a.name, sum(b.val) as sum_b_val
    from a left join b on a.id = b.a_id
    group by a.id
  ) as q1
  left join (
    select b.a_id, sum(c.val) as sum_c_val
    from b left join c on b.id = c.b_id
    group by b.a_id
  ) as q2 on q1.id = q2.a_id;
```

Check [this example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed0357/6).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Below query will work only if id in table A is unique.

```
select t1.name,t1.bval,t2.cval from 
 (select A.id, A.name, SUM(ISNULL(B.val,0)) bval
  from A
  left join b on a.id = b.A_id
  group by A.id, A.name) t1
left join
 (select B.A_Id, sum(ISNULL(c.val,0)) cval 
  from B
  left join c on b.id = c.b_id
  group by A_ID) t2
on t1.id = t2.A_Id;
```